# Expected unqualified-id

Tags: c++, algorithm, c++11

Im doing a random password generator but I have a problem at a switch.

*From case 4 to case 18 it says there is an "Expected unqualified-id" and points the '=' sign but I can't get the error.*

Is there a problem with the syntaxis or code?

***My code:***

```
switch (a) {
        case 0:
            char[1] = 'a';
            break;
        case 1:
            char[1] = 'b';
            break;
        case 2:
            char[1] = 'c';
            break;
        case 3:
            char[1] = 'd';
            break;
        case 4:
            char[1] = 'e';
            break;
```

Comment: Rename your array something other than `char`. That's a reserved word (how the compile made it that far, I can't say).

Comment: Does renaming that `char` array to something that isn't a  C++ reserved word help?

Comment: Will it help with the OP's quesion? It won't hurt, and you'll actually have a variable.

Comment: Realistically (but not perfectly portably), this switch could be replaced by `arr[1] = 'a' + a;` with whatever bounds checking.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because of the incompetence of the programmer expressed as a result their choice of variable naming.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Problem*: You can not name your array `char`, because this is a [reserved word in C++](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/keyword).

*Solution*: Rename your array and try again.